# wevtutil without admin permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-event-log, wevtutil

Is it possible to install a provider without admin permissions?

whenever I try something like `wevtutil im MyManifest.man` I got 'Access is denied.'.

If I run the same command in an admin command prompt it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as stated on the [wevtutil documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil), you should have looked at the EventLog SDK [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WES/windows-event-log-tools) which reads:

```
This command is limited to members of the Administrators group and must be run with elevated privileges.
```